# Entity Framework DatabaseFirst добавить навигационное свойство для связи между таблицами

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Как можно создать навигационное свойство без фактического изменения базы данных, т.е. без создания физической связи в бд.

Использу. EntityFramework ver. 5.0 подход DatabaseFisrt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавлением Assosiation в модель edmx. Правой клавишей на пустом месте - добавить Assosiation - и потом остается только удалить созданное автоматом поле и подставить свое (я это делал редактированием edmx, но может можно и как-то через интерфейс сделать).

Comment: т.е. Вы добавили связь между необходимыми Вам таблицами?! все свелось я так понимаю к этому

Comment: На уровне БД - нет. В бд были колонки с айдишниками, но физически в БД они не ключи. Выставил связь только в модели ЕФ вручную. СОбственно изначально была проблема в том, что оно автоматически добавляло колонку в таблицу и ставило связь по ней, а мне надо было по уже существующей.

Comment: у меня только один вопрос в случае изменения структуры бд не будет ли создан новый файл модели? если да то соответственно Ваши изменения пропадут.

Comment: Не будет. Модель на то и модель, что она как абстракция главнее.

Comment: ну Вам виднее DatabaseFirst не использую, удовлетворите мое любопытство: после добавления ассоциации у Вас изменился класс, Добавилось навигационное свойство в класс или нет?!

Comment: Да, добавилось. Там это можно настраивать, кстати.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29710/discussion-between-bald56rus-and-sss). я бы хотел у Вас кое что уточнить